# WebView shows blank white screen part from apple.com

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview

I have added a web view to my app however i keep getting a blank white screen when running on simulator or even device. When i enter apple.com as the website it works perfect but for any other website it just shows a blank white screen. 
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet var WebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


var URL = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")

WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))

}

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added autolayout to your webView? As the image below shows?
[image]

Just select your webView and click on **Add New Constraints** and set your constraints.

If this is not your issue, check the output window if it blocks requests that are not HTTPS, then you can add this code to your info.plist code.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

**Update**
You´re getting the white screen because you´re missing the http:// in your URL.

Comment: Try to change the URL from http:// to https:/ and see if it makes any difference. In your NSURL.

Comment: same issue, i don't get why apple.com works perfect and nothing else does

Comment: Have you added the NSAppTransportSecurity code that I added to your info.plist?

Comment: yes, all the steps have been followed as you showed above

Comment: Are you getting any messages in the console about web access?

Comment: @uz7, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @RashwanL No, still having the same issue

Comment: @uz7 did you solve this? If not send me a link so that I can download your project if you want.

Comment: @RashwanL what should i use to send you the link? where can i store the project?

Comment: @uz7 Google drive or dropbox.

Comment: @uz7, np glad to help. I have updated the solution in my post. Consider accepting the answer so that other can make use of it in the future.

Comment: Where can I find **Pin** ?

Comment: @Black, that was probably a typo. Should be "Add New Constraints".

Answer (score 0):

[image]In Plist of the app give App Transport Security Settings,Give dictionary and then under it Allow Arbitrary Loads And set bool to YES, as in iOS 9 you have to give https request, Or simply add https with url, it will work

Comment: No luck, I have the same picture as you have put however App Transport Security Settings says 0 items rather than 1 item

Comment: @uz7, that means you added the Allow Arbitrary Loads at the same level as App Transport Security Settings. Make sure the little triangle at the left is pointed down when you add an item so that it is subsidiary to the item with the triangle.

Comment: @uz7 just after App Transport Security Settings there must be a plus icon, tap on that then you can add items in a dictionary, and the item will be Allow Arbitrary Loads with bool YES

Comment: still having the same issue just a blank screen. only apple website seems to work.

Comment: @uz7, working for me. I tried several sites. Try to clean your project and remove it from the device/simulator and reinstall it.

Comment: @RashwanL I'm having the same issue, if you try www.redwoodcricket.co.uk see if that works for you. That is the site i'm having an issue with

Comment: @uz7 add http:// to the url and it will work for you so [http://www.redwoodcricket.co.uk](http://www.redwoodcricket.co.uk)

Comment: @RashwanL PERFECT!! Thank you very much